# Which lightweight markup languages can be converted to *.docx?

Tags: conversion, docx, markup

I've been trying out different lightweight text markup languages such as org-mode and Markdown.

Before making a decision on which one to use, which of these languages are known to be directly convertable to the Microsoft Word *.docx format?

I know Pandoc can convert Markdown, reStructuredText, textile, HTML, DocBook, or LaTeX to *.docx, but are there any other notable mentions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All of them.

Or at least any that can be converted to HTML, which is probably all of them. To convert to HTML, look at [what Github supports](https://github.com/github/markup/#markups):

- .markdown
- .textile
- .rdoc (Ruby documentation)
- .org (org-mode)
- .creole
- .mediawiki
- .rst (Python documentation)
- .asciidoc
- .pod

Github's converter program calls various Ruby libraries to do the conversion.

From HTML, you can convert to OOXML using Pandoc, or just open the HTML in MS Word.

Comment: Thanks so much!!! I never considered using HTML as an intermediary. This is good, because now I can focus just on which markup I like, without worrying about whether it can be turned into *.docx.